# Haskell layout tree

Tags: haskell, tree

Recently, I try to sovle the Haskell 99 Problems, the 66th (layout a tree compactly). I successed, but got confused by the solutions here(http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/66).

```
layout :: Tree a -> Tree (a, Pos)
layout t = t'
  where (l, t', r) = layoutAux x1 1 t
    x1 = maximum l + 1

    layoutAux :: Int -> Int -> Tree a -> ([Int], Tree (a, Pos), [Int])
    layoutAux x y Empty = ([], Empty, [])
    layoutAux x y (Branch a l r) = (ll', Branch (a, (x,y)) l' r', rr')
      where (ll, l', lr) = layoutAux (x-sep) (y+1) l
            (rl, r', rr) = layoutAux (x+sep) (y+1) r
            sep = maximum (0:zipWith (+) lr rl) `div` 2 + 1
            ll' = 0 : overlay (map (+sep) ll) (map (subtract sep) rl)
            rr' = 0 : overlay (map (+sep) rr) (map (subtract sep) lr)

-- overlay xs ys = xs padded out to at least the length of ys
-- using any extra elements of ys
overlay :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
overlay [] ys = ys
overlay xs [] = xs
overlay (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : overlay xs ys
```

why the caculation of 'x1' and 'sep' don't cause infinit loop?
How they been calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this to work is [non-strict evaluation mode](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_vs._non-strict) of Haskell rather than strict evaluation that you see in most languages.

In the example you have given, `maximum l` is possible to calculate because the `l` returned from `layoutAux` function doesn't contain any dependency on `x1`. `x1` is used in the `t'` part of the returned value.

Another simple example to show similar behavior is below code:

```
hello :: [Int] -> [Int]
hello x = x' where
  x' = hello' l x
  l = length x'
  hello' i lst = map (+i) lst
```

This will not loop forever because to get the length of a list you don't need to know it's content and that's why the list content dependency on `l` doesn't cause it to loop forever. Whereas if you had something like `maximum` instead of length, that would cause it to loop forever as `maximum` needs to know the content of list and the content depends on the result of `maximum`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can totally understand the non-strict evaluation in a small example, but still get lost when trying to read long codes, not to mention using it. So, is this kind of coding style recommend? If it is, where can I know more about it?

Comment: I too find this kind of exploit of non-strict evaluation a `tricky code` specially when the `deepness` of non-strict goes to a certain depth. But I think, may be, for some types of algorithm this can lead to much better performance characteristics.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes clear code is better, somtimes `tricky code` wins.I should learn more to understand such skill.